# SSL Certificate for Wordpress, IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, ssl-certificate

If they implement SSL on their wordpress site, will both the IOS and Android application automatically work through that SSL certificate or do we need to purchase another certificate. Please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apppresser creates a mobile wrapper around your site which means that any communication it has with the site will be over the protocol you have installed on the server. If you are using https:// when accessing the site when you create the app then it will be secure.

Comment: I will be using appPresser for creating mobile app. Then is that same with this as well.

Comment: Thankyou for clarifying my doubt.